# Extract i and j from a sparse Matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I can define a [sparse Matrix](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/Matrix/sparseMatrix) using a vector for i, j, and x:

```
i <- c(1,3:8)
j <- c(2,9,6:10)
x <- 7 * (1:7)
(A <- sparseMatrix(i, j, x = x))
```

I want to extract the `i`, `j`, and `x` elements from this sparse matrix, so I can re-create the matrix in another package.  This is easy with `i` and `x`:

```
i <- A@i + 1
x <- A@x
```

(Note that the order of i and x has changed, but their relative association is the same: i=4 is still in the same place as x=21)

However, the last element of the sparse matrix is `p`: "a numeric (integer valued) vector of pointers, one for each column (or row), to the initial (zero-based) index of elements in the column (or row)."

How can I convert `A@i` and `A@p` into the original `j` element used to define the matrix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a little tricky to figure out how columns is stored. I have a hard time explaining it, but maybe the code will help you get what is going on:

```
# Rows
A@i+1 
# [1] 1 4 5 6 3 7 8

# Cols (a little tricky..)
findInterval(seq(A@x)-1,A@p[-1])+1
# [1]  2  6  7  8  9  9 10

# Values
A@x
# [1]  7 21 28 35 14 42 49
```

So, after you remove the first element, `A@p` has one element for every column. The range of `A@p+1` is `1:length(A@x)`. Basically, for each column, it says that the first element of `A@x` that occurs in this column is located at this index of `A@x`. But the tricky part is that if *nothing* is located in that column, then it uses the index of the last column. That is my bad explanation... hopefully it will help in conjunction with the code.

Comment: Thanks! If I do `j <- findInterval(seq(A@x)-1,A@p[-1])+1` then `(B <- sparseMatrix(i, j, x = x))` then `all.equal(A, B)` I get true.  I've verified this on some other `dgCMatrix` objects, and the method works. Thank you!

Comment: Hm, I was just thinking about this and there might be some problems with the code with matrices with 0 or 1 element(s), so if you're writing code for this, you might want to examine the corner cases.

Comment: will do.  Fortunately, in my use case, the matrices have millions of elements.  If a matrix shows up with 0 or 1 elements the script will return an error before even getting past the first few lines.

Comment: The decryption of the rows and columns is a lot easier with the "TsparseMatrix" class. There you get both i and j and only need to remember that sparse classes are zero-based.

Answer (score 3):

Much easier with a TsparseMatrix object:

```
A <- as(A, "TsparseMatrix")
8 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"

[1,] . 7 . . .  .  .  .  .  .
[2,] . . . . .  .  .  .  .  .
[3,] . . . . .  .  .  . 14  .
[4,] . . . . . 21  .  .  .  .
[5,] . . . . .  . 28  .  .  .
[6,] . . . . .  .  . 35  .  .
[7,] . . . . .  .  .  . 42  .
[8,] . . . . .  .  .  .  . 49
> dput(A)
new("dgTMatrix"
    , i = c(0L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 7L)
    , j = c(1L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L)
    , Dim = c(8L, 10L)
    , Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL)
    , x = c(7, 21, 28, 35, 14, 42, 49)
    , factors = list()
)
```

Can also create but need to specify dimensions:

```
(A <- spMatrix(8,10, i=i, j=j, x = x))
```