# How to extract and record values, and their respective column/row information, from a matrix for 3D rendering?

Tags: r, matrix, data.table, rgl

I am bringing thermal images into R as 480 X 640 matrices. After isolating my "signal" (seedlings in a field), I would like to **export values to a data.table while also recording row and column of each observation**. I need a final data.table with basically x,y,z information. I am plotting the raw thermal matrices as a 3D surface in `rgl` and would like to make another 3D layer in my renderings that illustrates my "signal".

So I start with example data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
library(rgl)

dd <- data.table(c(1,0,1,2,1,0,2,1,0,2),
                 c(0,1,2,1,3,2,4,1,2,0),
                 c(3,2,1,3,2,4,3,2,1,0),
                 c(2,1,0,2,1,3,2,3,1,1),
                 c(0,1,2,1,3,2,0,1,1,3))

bb <- as.matrix(dd) # save a copy for later

find_signal = function(DT, max, min) {  # inverse of Dowle's NA remover
  for (j in seq_len(ncol(DT)))
    set(DT,which(DT[[j]] < min),j,NA)
  for (j in seq_len(ncol(DT)))
    set(DT,which(DT[[j]] > max),j,NA)
}

find_signal(dd, 2.0001, 1.9999)
```

So now, after eliminating "noise", my data.table contains only the values that correlate to my "signal". At this point it looks like this:

```
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
 1: NA NA NA  2 NA
 2: NA NA  2 NA NA
 3: NA  2 NA NA  2
 4:  2 NA NA  2 NA
 5: NA NA  2 NA NA
 6: NA  2 NA NA  2
 7:  2 NA NA  2 NA
 8: NA NA  2 NA NA
 9: NA  2 NA NA NA
10:  2 NA NA NA NA
```

I am working out how to export these values while recording their respective location in the thermal image. I need to export each observation and respective row and column information to another data.table. The purpose of this is to render another layer in the `rgl` scene and further analysis, like euclidean distance calculations.

The hypothetical output is as follows:

```
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4)
x <- c(10,9,8,7,6,7,6,5,4,3,4,3,2,1)
z <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

aa <- data.table(x,y,z)
```

And would look like this:

```
     x y z
 1: 10 1 2
 2:  9 2 2
 3:  8 3 2
 4:  7 4 2
 5:  6 5 2
 6:  7 1 2
 7:  6 2 2
 8:  5 3 2
 9:  4 4 2
10:  3 5 2
11:  4 1 2
12:  3 2 2
13:  2 3 2
14:  1 4 2
```

Allowing me to create an `rgl` scene like one rendered with the following code:

```
xb <- c(1:nrow(bb)); yb <- c(1:ncol(bb))

persp3d(x= xb, y= yb, z= bb, col = "blue")+
lines3d(aa$x[1:5], aa$y[1:5],  z= z+1, col = "green", lwd = 5)+  # my signal
lines3d(aa$x[6:10], aa$y[6:10], z= z+1,col = "green", lwd = 5)+
lines3d(aa$x[11:14], aa$y[11:14], z= z+1, col = "green", lwd = 5)
```

**Again, how can I export values from a data.table (or matrix) while simultaneously recording column and row number for each value?**

Thanks for advice

Comment: these might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555210/r-convert-matrix-or-data-frame-to-sparsematrix and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099612/extract-i-and-j-from-a-sparse-matrix

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thank you... the linked content looks promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the index of each entry of the matrix by using the `row()` and `col()` functions.  So for your example:

```
keep <- !is.na(bb)
cbind( x = row(bb)[keep], y = col(bb)[keep], z = bb[keep]  )
```

which produces this output:

```
       x y z
 [1,]  4 1 2
 [2,]  7 1 2
 [3,] 10 1 2
 [4,]  3 2 2
 [5,]  6 2 2
 [6,]  9 2 2
 [7,]  2 3 2
 [8,]  5 3 2
 [9,]  8 3 2
[10,]  1 4 2
[11,]  4 4 2
[12,]  7 4 2
[13,]  3 5 2
[14,]  6 5 2
```

It's not in the order you asked for; use `order()` if that matters.